# Programming logic IF Then

Tags: c#, if-statement, logic

I deal with this type of issue all the time and was wondering if you had any slick elegant work arounds:

```
if(myObject != null && myObject.myProperty != myValue){
//do something
}else{
//do something else
}
```

If I run this logic, I get null reference when myObject is null so I end up doing:

```
if(myObject != null){
    if(myObject.myProperty != myValue){
        //do something
    }else{
        //do something else
    }
}else{
    //do something else
}
```

So I end up having redundant code on my "do something else"  how do you guys handle this?

Comment: Are you sure that you have two `&` symbols in your code for the first one?  If you have only one, you'd expect a null reference.  Two should prevent that.

Comment: How exactly `do something else's are different here?

Comment: Your first code segment is valid

Comment: Are you sure about that? If `myObject` is null, it will short circuit your if statement and work exactly as expected.

Comment: You don't have to pair each `if` with `else`. Just remove the `else` of the first `if`

Comment: If `myObject` is `null` it wont evaluate the second condition, if it's not `null` it shouldn't throw NullReferenceException. Your first code is fine!

Comment: @NikolaD-Nick, that won't work, he'll miss the case when `myObject.myProperty == myValue`

Comment: The first case should work perfectly fine. What's wrong with it? Since it is an and operator, the check will return false the moment myobject == null and it won't check the second clause. Am I missing something here???

Comment: Hmmm...You are correct, no idea what I was doing before..it is working now with my first code sample..

Comment: @sybkar I thought that he was accessing myObject in the else part of the first example if the myObject was null, that's why I commented. Didn't know that he didn't even try his code ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first check for `null` means that the second condition won't be evaluated if that isn't met - when using logical AND (`&&`) - so I suggest your null reference exception comes from elsewhere, not that latter condition.

Comment: Nice explanation, I will choose this an the answer

Answer (score 2):

There is no "elegant" way to deal with this - two ways of sharing the code of "do something else" are really of varying degree of non-elegance:

- You can put the "do something else" code into a function, or
- Define a flag before entering the `if` to say if additional processing is needed, and act on the flag upon exit from the `if` statement.

The first solution is self-explanatory; the second solution looks like this:

```
var processed = false;
if(myObject != null) {
    if(myObject.myProperty != myValue){
        //do something
        processed = true;
    }
    // do more stuff knowing that myObject is not null
}
if (!processed) {
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: ++ I've had to use this construct before, and I'm glad to get confirmation that there was little way around it.

Comment: But from what I can see the OP doesn't actually have said 'problem'.

Answer (score -2):

your first statement is perfectly valid.

```
if(myObject != null && myObject.MyProperty != myValue)
```

What this will do is it will evaluate `myObject != null` first, and since there's a `&&` to the right of it, If it's false, it doesn't even need to evaluate the other clause.

If you just copy and paste the code you pasted here, I think you'll find that it runs successfully

Comment: This has syntax mistakes, too. Wrong case for `if`, and `!-` doesn't make sense.